# Find 3D vector's length using Eigen library

Tags: vector, eigen

Please, could anyone tell me a way to find 3D vector's length using Eigen library (v.3 if probable)?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called the norm of a vector:

```
Vector3f v;
float length = v.norm();
```